# How to retrive children from a single object intead of array in json-server?

Tags: json, typescript, backend, json-server

I am using json-server for mock-backend to retrive children form a single object. 
The parent table `sentinel` and the child table `sensor`

[image: the table sentinel]

[image: the sensor table]

As you can see the `sensors` is an array and `sentinel` is an object. 
I have used `http://localhost:3000/sentinel?_embed=sensors` but the response is not what i am expecting, because I want `sensors: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, ecc]`
[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTugQ.png]

The [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#relationships) shows that are two ways to retrive two tables:
_embed (include children) and _expand (include parent).

How could I achive this result?

Comment: How is it `sentinel` to represent a table if it's a single objet? Can you have more than one `sentinel` in your db? ([Please do note upload images of code on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question))

Comment: @Ibsn Thanks for the answer, i will not post images anymore. I'm new to the programming language world so I am sorry if my words are not 'technical'. Assuming that `db.json` is a MySQL db in the table `sentinel` i will have just a single record, and with a single GET request i want to retrive the `sentinel` information plus all `sensors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `sentinel` is a single object in your `db.json` and you can't have more than one `sentinel` it is not clear to me how your query is different from retrieving all sensors with `sentinelId=10`:

```
/sensors?sentinelId=10
```

In fact if you try this API:

```
/sentinel/10/sensors
```

it will work, because json-server rewrite the url exactly to the previous query.

If for some reason you don't want to use the `sentinel` id directly in the query, the other option is to use json-server as a module and define a custom route with the logic you need. Here's a basic example that exposes a `/sentinel/sensors` API and retrieve `sentinel` data along with the sensors whose `sentinelId` equals to the current `sentinel` id:

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('./db.json');
const db = router.db;

server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);
server.get('/sentinel/sensors', (req, res) => {
  const sentinel = db.get('sentinel').value();
  const sensors = db
    .get('sensors')
    .filter({ sentinelId: sentinel.id })
    .value();
  res.send({ ...sentinel, sensors: sensors });
});
server.use(router);
server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Mock server is running on port ' + 3001);
});
```

That would give you a response like this:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "name": "Sentinel",
  "sensors": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sentinelId": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "sentinelId": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-orycbz?file=index.js)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both your API retrive just `sensors` information but i need
`sensors` nested into object `sentinel` using route parameter without define a custom route (if it is possible)

Comment: That is not possible unless in your `db.json` you define `sentinel` as a list with a single item. In that case `_embed` would work. I update the answer to let the custom route return the response you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the example and the explanation, it worked!!

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer.